# three.js CameraHelper rotates faster than PerspectiveCamera

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a THREE.PerspectiveCamera to which I add a THREE.CameraHelper.

```
cameraLocal = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, 1, 20, 120);
scene.add(cameraLocal);
cameraLocalHelper = new THREE.CameraHelper(cameraLocal);
cameraLocal.add(cameraLocalHelper);
```

However when I rotate the camera,

```
cameraLocal.rotateX(0.1);
```

the CameraHelper rotates by a larger amount than the camera. 
I've made a
[demo that shows this](http://mytestpages.com/rgh/camerahelper-demo-01.html).
Initially, cameraLocal can't see the help lines drawn by the CameraHelper. However, if cameraLocal is rotated either way about the x-axis, the help lines come into view, I'm supposing on account of the CameraHelper rotating by a different amount.

Could anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

I'm using the build of three.js from 5-Aug-2019.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CameraHelper` needs to be added directly to the scene.

Do not try to add it as a child of the camera itself.

three.js r.107